# Phone + Angular + Facebook

Tags: angularjs, html, facebook, cordova, phonegap-build

I am creating an angular app, that will later be compiled on phonegap for android and ios. i have tried numerous plugins to integrate into facebook (mainly for login and sharing to facebook) on development - in the chrome browser while running on phonegap server, this works well. 
I am able to click and share or have the pop up screen for permissions come up. however when i compile the the code and run it on a device it no longer works. i am suspecting this is because the the app does not have access to the device browser? or does not allow pop up in app? How can i resolve this problem? is cordova inapp the only way?

Comment: Please **answer the following questions in your post**. Since this appears to be your first post on this subject. Is this your first hybrid App?
Are you using the *Phonegap Desktop App*? Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ? Please do not assume the answer, please read the link. Once you have answer the question *in the post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.

Comment: Thank you for your relpy, I am using Phonegap cli, To initiate the app server i run command phonegap serv. I also checked just to make sure, cordova command or -v and it is not install (as far as i know from this test) my project has a folder called hybrid in here i have www (which has my app angular files and html partials,css,images, index and nothing more)
i do not have cordova.js in my project thus far @JesseMonroy650

Comment: I am not sure if this may be on any help but i use adobe's phonegap build to build an apk

Comment: Does page look familiar http://docs.phonegap.com/ ?

Comment: unfortunately not, but now fortunately so! I will go through the steps. This will help with my above issue correct? Or is it just to get the application standards correct?

Comment: NO. DON'T. This is a beginners app, meant for teaching and testing. Using it will confuse you. Let me write what you need to do.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 thanks, awaiting your response

Comment: if you really are using *CLI*, please exchange the *phonegap-build* tag for *phonegap-cli*.

Comment: Since the fix I gave you did not work, i deleted it. Your issue is with Angular. You will need these instructions in the future. [HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md)

Answer (score 1):

The updated cordova version doesn't allow the app to make any request outside the app. You need to follow the instructions in order to make it work.

Add the "[Cordova Whitelist Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist)" in your config.xml

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.1.0" />
```

Or simply

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.1.0" />
```

Try putting the following in your config.xml

```
<content src="index.html" />
```

is the path to your HTML file inside the source directory.

```
<access origin="*" />
```

will allow you to make a request anywhere from your app.

At the end, put the following intents

```
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
```

It will solve your problem. Give it a try and let me know!